# video thumbnail of selected video while uploading on firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, video, thumbnails

i am uploading video to firebase storage. i want to show the thumbnail of selected video on app screen

i have tried uploading image with the same code and it gives me the image preview of selected image, but it doesnot show any preview or thumbnail of selected video

moreover i want to know hoe to give the path of selected video as well..

**main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST = 3;
    Button chooseImg, uploadImg;
    ImageView imgView;
    int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 111;
    Uri filePath;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    //creating reference to firebase storage
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<<ur app url>>");    //change the url according to your firebase app

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chooseImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chooseImg);
        uploadImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadImg);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Uploading....");


        chooseImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        uploadImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(filePath != null) {
                    pd.show();

                    StorageReference childRef = storageRef.child("vide.mp4");

                    //uploading the image
                    UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.putFile(filePath);

                    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Failed -> " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select a video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            filePath = data.getData();

            try {
                //getting image from gallery
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);

                //Setting image to ImageView
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you done this

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran  no i could not achieve this....i changed my design and uploaded video without preview